# How do I start the VNC server?

Tags: vnc

How can start the VNC server to make my desktop accessible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Install vino:

```
sudo apt-get install vino
```

Configure vino:

```
vino-preferences
```

It open this windows :

[image]

You start the server with :

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

Enter this command in your Autostarted Apps if you wish vino to start automatically.

Comment: I would advise to use vino over ssh, because it isn't a secure application. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH?action=show&redirect=SSH%2FOpenSSH

Comment: For that last step, `System > Preferences > Startup Applications` should already have a "Remote Desktop" entry that just needs to be ticked. http://imgur.com/s4iTd.png

Comment: @andrewsomething - it was not the case on xunbutu.

Comment: You should tag your question with xubuntu otherwise people will assume you're using a default ubuntu setup.

Comment: @Jorge, I think vino is a gnome tool ans work the same way in ubuntu.  The only difference is the entry in startup application mentionned by andrewsomething.

Comment: There is no vino-preferences in Xubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Works for me in xenial 16.04

Answer (score 6):

Here is the whole process I do to utilize VNC, simplified

---

ONE. SETUP server

install VNC: `sudo apt-get install vnc`

install openssh-server: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

---

TWO. SETUP remote access PC

install PuTTY

install VNC or VNC viewer

---

THREE. Connect and Launch:

From remote access PC:

1. Run PuTTY
2. Connect SSH into the servers IP
3. Log into the server with Login ID and Password
4. A Run: `sudo x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess`

   B Else if that doesn't work, run: `sudo x11vnc -display :0 -auth <insert your path to your .Xauthority>`

   C Else if that doesn't work, run the commands again but as root.

Then once connection is established...

5. Launch VNC viewer
6. When prompted, enter the servers IP and connect

You now have accessed your server via VNC and should be able to control and interact with that desktop.

Good Luck and Enjoy!!

Comment: Thx! I'm using this method and can connect in the active session; But the connection just still alive for fell seconds and ends showing:
> Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
> viewer exited.
> deleted 45 tile_row polling images.
Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

For a bit more security, I don't leave VNC running the whole time.  I SSH into the machine and then start the VNC server using the following command:

x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -display :0

For ease I have the command in a shell script, so it is just a case of SSH to the server, followed by the command startvnc.sh.

This way once you disconnect VNC is no longer available.

For even more security you can tunnel VNC over the SSH connection.

This [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/tunneling-vnc-connections-over-ssh-howto.html) provides details on how to forward the correct ports.

Answer (score 4):

As root, run:

```
sudo apt-get install vino
```

As your user, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
vino-preferences
# replace eth0 in the following with your network interface
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino network-interface eth0
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

A script can be written to automaticly start `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` or you can just have your window manager start it directly once it loads and your network is UP, this method worked for me because I was having security type 18 issues with windows VNC Viewer not connecting and I had to turn off encryption

Comment: I also did `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino vnc-password ''` for no password and `gsettings set org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false` to skip the acceptance prompt on the host computer, which should be fine for a trusted local network. (Make sure the router is not forwarding external connections to port 5900 on the host computer)